# Filtering data inside .NET core controllers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

So I want to apply different filters to a certain set of data from a database, let's say I want to get only the movies of a certain genre, and based on that filtered data to search a certain movie by its name from those filtered movies. In this tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-3.1) they do the filtering of the data(movies) all within 1 click of a button through the Index function.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string movieGenre, string searchString)
        {
            // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
            IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Movie
                                            orderby m.Genre
                                            select m.Genre;

            var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                         select m;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
            {
                movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
            }

            var movieGenreVM = new MovieGenreViewModel
            {
                Genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync()),
                Movies = await movies.ToListAsync()
            };

            return View(movieGenreVM);
        }
```

And the View:

```
<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>

        <select asp-for="MovieGenre" asp-items="Model.Genres">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>

        Title: <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>
```

But what do I do if I want to have different buttons for different types of filtering and I want do the second filtering on the already filtered data by the first button. How am I gonna get that previous data that was filtered already to filter it further more?

If I do something like this:

```
<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>

        <select asp-for="MovieGenre" asp-items="Model.Genres">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>

<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>


        Title: <input type="text" asp-for="SearchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Then I can't just choose a movie genre, filter, then choose a search string and make the search on the already filtered movies because I will always get the full data from the database on each call of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all filters in the Index method. `Index(FilterModel model)`

```
public class FilterModel
{
     public FilterType Filter {get;set;}
     public string Filter1..
     public string Filter2..
     etc..
}

public enum FilterType { ByName, ByDate, etc... }
```

Based on enum value which should be passed based on button click you can build the `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate`, and pass that to the `Where()` clause.

As an example

```
Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate = x => true;

if(model.Filter == FilterType.ByName)
{
    predicate = x => x.Name == moedl.Filter1;
} 
else
{
}

var filtered = dbContext.Movies.Where(predicate);
..
```

This is just an example to give an idea how you can improve it further.
But I usually use enums to determine the filtering I want to do.

The enum value should come from the view, if you have multiple views with different forms, then you can hardcode the enum value in the form using a hidden field, otherwise maybe a dropdown would help.

You can use the same method for POST,GET but make sure to check for the `model != null`.
If null dont filter.

Another option would be to enhance a little bit the FilterModel and use `Dictionary<string, string> Values` instead of `Filter1`, `Filter2` etc, but this depends on the complexity of the use case.

Sorry I could not prove a more realistic example but hope this leads to the right direction.